# Twitter API: Twitter has private access in ... error

Tags: java, api, twitter

When I create Twitter class object I get an error that this has private access in the package, I need Twitter class to invoke webhooks method. I described in the code section what I want to get.

I use org.apache.streams:streams-provider-twitter dependency.
Here is a link to org.apache.streams.

[streams-provider-twitter](http://apache.github.io/streams/streams-contrib/streams-provider-twitter/index.html)

Below it's what I have in my code:

```
TwitterConfiguration twitterConfiguration = new TwitterConfiguration();

        TwitterOAuthConfiguration twitterOAuth = new TwitterOAuthConfiguration();
        twitterOAuth.setAccessToken(accessToken);
        twitterOAuth.setAccessTokenSecret(tokenSecret);
        twitterOAuth.setConsumerKey(SecurityConstants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        twitterOAuth.setConsumerSecret(SecurityConstants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

        twitterConfiguration.setOauth(twitterOAuth);

Twitter twitter = new Twitter(); // here I get error that Twitter has private access, 

//I need Twitter class to invoke:

twitter.registerWebhook("endopint");
twitter.getWebhooks();
```

Can you post example how use this dependency to retrieve webhooks ? I don't know what class use to invoke webhook method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the constructor yourself. Use [the factory method](http://apache.github.io/streams/streams-contrib/streams-provider-twitter/apidocs/org/apache/streams/twitter/api/Twitter.html#getInstance-org.apache.streams.twitter.TwitterConfiguration-):

```
Twitter twitter = Twitter.getInstance(twitterConfiguration);
```

Comment: I get NullPointerException when I try call this line.